# Possible bug in vehicleWeight parameter for costs calculation in the Here Fleet Telematics Toll Costs Api

Tags: here-api

In the documentation I see:
vehicleWeight -- Number. Actual total weight of vehicle incl. its payload but NOT the trailers' weight or payload.

For me the truck itself is 12t. While trying to get costs for toll roads with this value, I'm getting distance 470km, costs 58Eur and it is wrong.

So, I want to know what is the problem: 1) documentation error, vehicleWeight should be mass truck+trailer, 2) I missed some extra parameters, 3) or maybe some other issue?

When I tryied to change vehicleWeight from 12t to 20t (truck+trailer mass) the result is correct, about 85Eur.

```
https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=2&emissionType=6&height=4.0m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=12t&limitedWeight=20t&tiresCount=10&commercial=1&cost_optimize=0&driver_cost=0.0&vehicle_cost=0.0&currency=EUR&rollup=country;tollsys&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!49.4889567,10.978884&waypoint1=geo!passThrough!50.1211273,8.4961394&waypoint2=geo!stopOver!51.2383707,6.6739259&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&vehicleType=diesel,28
```

I expect to get here about 85Eur (because distance is about 470km and price for Euro 6, >18t, 4 axles is 0.187cents/km), but actually API returning about 58Eur.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue. It seems that there was an issue and we could solve it already. Within the next release planned for February this will be solved.